# SwiftUI: How can I get server data to display?

Tags: swiftui, combine

**Scenario:** Accessing data (of variable size) from a server and display it.  In this case, an array of countries.

Server access should be *called once(1)* upon entering this View (or before).

**Observation:** I can see the data via debugger & print statements within the publisher.

**Problem:** Data doesn't display within View.

The following is the ENTIRE code (reduced to a simple request for an array of countries via playground).

Please feel free to cut/paste into playground. 
It should run as expected, but doesn't display any data.

**Solution?**

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

struct VaccinesDataView: View {
    @State private var appleData: [String]?
    @StateObject var appleCountries = AppleCountries()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Apple Data")
            }) {
                if let vacData = appleData {
                    ForEach(vacData, id: \.self) { source in

                        HStack {
                            Text(source)
                                .font(.title)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Vaccines", displayMode: .inline)
        }.onAppear {
            self.appleCountries.getData()
        }

        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

// =====================================================================================================

class AppleCountries: ObservableObject {
    @Published var appleData: [String]?

    func getData() {
        let appleURL = URL(string: "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/apple/countries")!
        let remoteDataPublisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: appleURL)
            .map(\.data)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .decode(type: [String].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .print("Apples: ")

        remoteDataPublisher
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    print("Publisher Finished")
                case let .failure(anError):
                    Swift.print("\nReceived error: ", anError)
                }
            }, receiveValue: { someValue in
                self.appleData = someValue
                print("appleData: \(String(describing: self.appleData))")
            }).store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(VaccinesDataView())
```

**Hint:** I notice REPEATED access to server, when I only want one (1).

The server access is via **.onAppear()** which is *probably* called multiple times.

```
Apples: : receive subscription: (Decode)
Apples: : request unlimited
Apples: : receive subscription: (Decode)
Apples: : request unlimited
Apples: : receive subscription: (Decode)
Apples: : request unlimited
Apples: : receive subscription: (Decode)
Apples: : request unlimited
Apples: : receive value: (["Albania", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", "Cambodia", "Canada", "Chile", "Colombia", "Croatia", "Czechia", "Denmark", "Egypt", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Japan", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macao", "Malaysia", "Mexico", "Morocco", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Norway", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "S. Korea", "Romania", "Russia", "Saudi Arabia", "Serbia", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Taiwan", "Thailand", "Turkey", "Ukraine", "UAE", "UK", "USA", "Uruguay", "Vietnam"])
appleData: Optional(["Albania", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", "Cambodia", "Canada", "Chile", "Colombia", "Croatia", "Czechia", "Denmark", "Egypt", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Japan", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macao", "Malaysia", "Mexico", "Morocco", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Norway", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "S. Korea", "Romania", "Russia", "Saudi Arabia", "Serbia", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Taiwan", "Thailand", "Turkey", "Ukraine", "UAE", "UK", "USA", "Uruguay", "Vietnam"])
Apples: : receive finished
Publisher Finished
Apples: : receive value: (["Albania", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", "Cambodia", "Canada", "Chile", "Colombia", "Croatia", "Czechia", "Denmark", "Egypt", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Japan", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macao", "Malaysia", "Mexico", "Morocco", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Norway", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "S. Korea", "Romania", "Russia", "Saudi Arabia", "Serbia", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Taiwan", "Thailand", "Turkey", "Ukraine", "UAE", "UK", "USA", "Uruguay", "Vietnam"])
appleData: Optional(["Albania", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", "Cambodia", "Canada", "Chile", "Colombia", "Croatia", "Czechia", "Denmark", "Egypt", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Japan", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macao", "Malaysia", "Mexico", "Morocco", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Norway", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "S. Korea", "Romania", "Russia", "Saudi Arabia", "Serbia", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Taiwan", "Thailand", "Turkey", "Ukraine", "UAE", "UK", "USA", "Uruguay", "Vietnam"])
Apples: : receive finished
Publisher Finished
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need extra state `appleData` - it is not filled - use `appleCountries` directly as below.

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
struct VaccinesDataView: View {
    @StateObject var appleCountries = AppleCountries()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Apple Data")
            }) {
                if let vacData = appleCountries.appleData {    //  !!
                    ForEach(vacData, id: \.self) { source in

                        HStack {
                            Text(source)
                                .font(.title)
                        }.onAppear {
                            appleCountries.getData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Vaccines", displayMode: .inline)
        }.onAppear {
            self.appleCountries.getData()
        }

        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: When I remove the '.appleData' I get the following warning: Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'AppleCountries' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'